# JavaFX equivalent to ListView in Android

Tags: android, javafx

Is there a JavaFX equivalent to the Android SDK's listview where you can customize the items to have a specific layout using xml?

For instance in Android, if every item needs to have two text boxes for two separate properties, you can make a custom ArrayAdapter and populate the listview using that.

As far as I know, the ListView in FX isn't built for that.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The equivalent to `ListView` is called `ListView`... set the `cellFactory` to customize how the cells are displayed. The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/ListView.html) covers this pretty fully if you follow the links. That said, if you have two separate properties for every item in the list, it sounds as though you should be using a `TableView`.

Comment: I was using that as a simple example, my intent is that every item has a label and multiple buttons arranged specifically. Thanks for the guidance.